# Why can't I define this?

Tags: python, discord.py

the code do run well before
I moved codes in class
and it didn't run :(

```
class Clear(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("============== Log clear system on ready.")

    @commands.command(aliases=['청소'])
    async def clear(ctx, amount=11):
        if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages):
            await ctx.send('이런, 권한이 없어 데이터를 지울 수 없어요.')
        return

    amount = amount+1

    async def clear(ctx, amount=11):
        if amount > 101:
            await ctx.send('100개보다 더 많은 메세지를 지우는 건 불가능해요!')
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            await ctx.send('데이터를 초기화 하였어요.')

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Clear(bot))`
```

this is my code and I don't know how to define "amount"

Comment: you never declare what `amount` is.

Comment: I can't understand. Where the code says `amount = amount+1`, what do you think should be the value used for `amount` ahead of time, in order to add the `1`? Where do you think it should come from, and why should that work? And **when** do you expect this code to run?

Comment: at start you have to define `amount = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the declaration of the clear command. For amount to be recognized, you need to declare the clear function within the class and use the @commands.command decorator for it to work properly with ctx.

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Clear(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("============== Log clear system on ready.")

    @commands.command(aliases=['청소'])
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=11):
        if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            await ctx.send('이런, 권한이 없어 데이터를 지울 수 없어요.')
            return
        
        amount = amount + 1
        
        if amount > 101:
            await ctx.send('100개보다 더 많은 메세지를 지우는 건 불가능해요!')
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            await ctx.send('데이터를 초기화 하였어요.')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Clear(bot))
```